# Can't copy from GPU to CPU (OpenGL)

Tags: c++, opengl

Here is my texture class:

```
struct GPUAllocation {
    uint ID,VectorType,DataType,Width,Height,Format,IntFormat;
    //ID is the output from glGen* and Format is the format of the texture and IntFormat
    //is the Internal Format of this texture. (Width and height and too obvious)
    //DataType is like GL_FLOAT...
    bool isFinalized;
    GPUAllocation(uint vectorType,uint dataType,uint width,uint height);
    void SetSlot(int n);
    void Finalize();
    ~GPUAllocation();
};
```

Code to copy from this texture to RAM:

```
void memcpy(GPUAllocation src,void* dst) {
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,src.ID); //ID is the output from glGen*
    glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,0,0,src.Width,src.Height,src.Format,src.DataType,dst);
}
```

The code that runs this function is:

```
GPUAllocation gpu_alloc(PCPU_Vector1,PCPU_Float,4096,4096); //I generate Format and IntFormat here.
//The generated format is correct because when I copied from GPU to CPU I didn't got any error
float *cpu_alloc=new float[4096*4096];
memcpy(gpu_alloc,cpu_alloc); //The error occurred here!
```

The error that occurred was `1281`.

---

EDIT:
I found when I copying from GPU to CPU and then CPU to GPU I got that error. If I first copy from GPU to CPU I didn't got any error.
The function that copies from CPU to GPU is:

```
void memcpy(void* src,GPUAllocation dst) {
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,dst.ID);
    glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,dst.Format,dst.DataType,src);
}
```

Comment: "I found when I copying from GPU to CPU and then CPU to GPU I got that error. If I first copy from GPU to CPU I didn't got any error". The GL will allocate storage on the GPU when you call `glTexImage*`. If you try to read a texture, for which no storage is yet allocated, you get an error. Btw, the way you have written the two `memcpy` functions, the destination is the first parameter. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`glTexSubImage*` functions copy **to** the texture, not from. Use `glReadPixels` for reading a texture from GL to client memory.

I would also strongly recommend watching [Optimized Texture Transfers](http://www.gputechconf.com/gtcnew/on-demand-gtc.php?topic=14#1414)

PS. Err, of course, `glReadPixels` reads from the framebuffer, not from a texture, `glGetTexImage` reads from a texture.

Comment: Then what is `glGetTexImage`?

Comment: Another one I tried `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,src.ID); glReadPixels(0,0,src.Width,src.Height,src.Format,src.DataType,dst);` and I got `1286` error... I think I don't know how to use it :S.

Comment: @chill: It's noteworthy that in OpenGL-ES there is no glGetTexImage and one has indeed render the texture to a/the framebuffer and retrive the data with glReadPixels. But in ordinary OpenGL glGetTexImage is the method of choice of course.